# Change null values to string based on value in another column

Tags: sql, select, case

I want to replace NULL values in an integer column (pr_id) with text "N/A" if the value in a different column (type) = X. If the value in pr_id is not NULL, then the query should return the value in pr_id.

```
SELECT p_id,
       pr_id,
       type,
       CASE
         WHEN type = 'X' THEN COALESCE(CAST(pr_id AS VARCHAR(255)), 'N/A')
         ELSE pr_id
       END AS pr_id
FROM   a
```

I'm getting the error:
*CASE types bigint and character varying cannot be matched*

I thought that by using case + coalesce, I would be able to circumvent the mismatch between bigint and varchar, but doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: My guess s that you need to cast pr_id even when you're using it as-is, so that the result column is always a varchar.

Comment: A case expression always returns the same data type, you need to explicitly cast the value to varchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All branches of the `case` expression should return the same type (or at least, types that can be implicitly converted to each other). Here, the `when` branch returns a `varchar` but the `else` branch returns a `bigit`. You can solve this error by adding a `cast` to the `else` branch too:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN type = 'X' THEN COALESCE (CAST(pr_id AS VARCHAR(255)), 'N/A')
  ELSE CAST(pr_id AS VARCHAR(255) -- Here!
END AS pr_id
```

Comment: You _could_ solve this with a `cast`, but I'd recommend solving it (if possible) by just letting the SQL continue to return `NULL`, and handling this in the client code or reporting tool.

Answer (score 2):

I have translated the description literally:

```
CASE
   WHEN type = 'X' AND pr_id IS NULL THEN 'N/A'
   ELSE CAST(pr_id AS VARCHAR(20))
END AS pr_id_str
```

The important thing here is that all branches of `CASE` expressions need to return same data type so the bigint needs to be converted to string data type.